# How can I do a foreach loop using php dictionaries?

Tags: php, dictionary, foreach

I am trying to make a php navbar sort of thing. I have the html code and what I want to do is to use a php dictionary ("Home"=>"http://www.domain.com/") and turn it into html code.

Comment: In PHP we call them Associative Arrays. ;) Almost went all .Net on you, till I saw you are a python guy.

Comment: @DampeS8N I have to fight the urge to call them dicts every day.

Comment: The worst is that dictionaries in .Net aren't like dicts + assoc arrays in py'n'php... They aren't hashtables.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
<ul>
<?php foreach ($links as $title => $url): ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo htmlentities($url); ?>"><?php echo htmlentities($title); ?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 16):

```
foreach($arr as $key=>$value) {
    // your code here
}
```

I have no idea how you want to make your navbar, but with any knowledge of HTML you should be able to go from here.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (dict as $key => $value){
    echo "<a href='$value'>$key</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Fastest

```
<?php
foreach($array as $name => $link){
    echo '<a href="',$link,'">',$name,'</a>\n';
}
?>
```

Easier to read and understand but slower

```
<?php
foreach($array as $name => $link){
    echo "<a href='$link'>$name</a>\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: please don't tell people to do micro-optimisations that make little difference

Comment: I didn't. I offered two options. One is faster, the other is easier. It pays to know both.

Comment: Yeah, although it probably barely matters anymore @DampeS8N, I feel like you did the right thing giving both options.  When you get into the billions of operations, it makes a massive difference.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if i understand the question but you can use an hash like this:

```
<?php 
    $navBar = array( 
        "Home" => "http://www.domain.com/",
        "Info" => "http://www.domain.com/info/",
      );
      foreach($navBar as $key => $val){ 
        echo "<li>$key => $val<li>"; 
    } 
?>
```